# is it possible to set the position of a label relative to the key in gnuplot?

Tags: text, position, gnuplot, legend, label

The nature of my plot is such that absolute labels don't really work; I can't restrict the range in y, so wondered if there was a way to either include my label text inside the key or have it placed relative to the key (i.e. below)

```
set term png enhanced size 1024,768
set title "{/=15 1D My title}\n - by me"
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
set label "V_0 = 10\n E = 1" #this is the bit I want to reposition
set out 'trial.png'
set xrange [-2.5:2.5]
set arrow from -2,-2000 to -2,2000 nohead size screen 0.025,30,45 ls 1
set arrow from 2,-2000 to 2,2000 nohead size screen 0.025,30,45 ls 1
plot 'data.dat'
```

PS: also, is there a better way to get my vertical lines at x = -2 and x = 2? The arrows solution is again not ideal since my y range is often greater or smaller than 2000.

Comment: Could you give some example data that shows the problems?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In gnuplot you can use different coordinate systems to set arrows, labels, key and objects. The coordinates may be specified as

- `first`: value on the left and bottom axes.
- `second`: value on the right and top axes.
- `graph`: relative to the area within the axes, `0,0` is bottom left and `1,1` is top right.
- `screen`: relative to the entire canvas.
- `character`: depends on the chosen font size.

With this, you can set your arrows in the following way:

```
set arrow from first -2,graph 0 to first -2,graph 1 nohead ls 1
set arrow from first 2,graph 0 to first 2,graph 1 nohead ls 1
```

You don't need to set a `size` if you don't have an arrow head.

Although I did not fully understand your label question, I'm sure you will solve it with these information about different coordinate types:

```
set label "V_0 = 10\n E = 1" right at graph 0.9, graph 0.8
```