# gnuplot - "How to draw an asymptote" / "Get axis value range", get x or y axis minimum and maximum values

Tags: plot, gnuplot, axis, asymptote

Is it possible to "get" the x/y (or other) axis plot range values?

The reason I am trying to do this is that I want to plot a vertical line on my graph at the position of an asymptotic point... Perhaps there is an alternative or better way of doing this than drawing an arrow (with no head) on the graph?

Comment: You can use different coordinate systems to position your arrow, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17919454/2604213. I guess this should work for you without explicitely knowing the plot range

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Christoph (again) I have been able to do the following:

```
#Plot asymptote
set arrow from b,graph 0 to b,graph 1 lt 2 lw 2 lc rgb "green" nohead
```

This code does the following:

- draws an arrow
- start position: x=variable `b`, y=graph 0 (minimum of graph [y] axis)
- end position: x=variable `b`, y=graph 1 (maximum of graph [y] axis)
- line type 2 (may require `set termoption dashed` to enable dashed lines, consult documentation)
- line width 2
- line color green
- no arrow head (a line)